# Access cookie before View loaded in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a cookie with value "OLD", then I update the cookie with following code :

```
var lang = new HttpCookie("lang");
lang.Value = "NEW";
lang.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2);

HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(lang); //set updated cookie value

var x = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("lang");
```

`x` will still have "OLD" as value because it's not being sent to the client. Is it possible to get the updated value without it being sent to client first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

you are setting the cookie in `HttpContext.Current.Response` and trying to find it in `HttpContext.Current.Request` even before the next request has come to server.

It is not going to work.

## My Advice

For this case, use of cookie is incorrect. You have other options better fit for purpose, like -

1. ViewData
2. ViewBag
3. TempData
4. Session
5. ViewModel

## The Answer

But if you still want to use cookie this way, search the cookie in `HttpContext.Current.Response`. I am sure you will get it.

Like this:

```
var cookieValue = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["OLD"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send value to client side and only want to use for reference you can use `TempData` for your purpose. Which might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should look for it in Response, not in Request, because request - it's that came from client.